# Configure file missing from postgres binary

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Thanks for looking into my question.

I have downloaded postgres from https://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.6.5-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz several times.

But, when I untar it and see, I am not able to find configure file to run the command.

Please provide me the inputs about this.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: you only need `configure` if you want to build from source. If you downloaded the binaries you don't need that.

Comment: ohh yeah. Thank you.
I picked binaries instead of source.